# What does the violence hologram in "THX 1138" mean?

Tags: thx-1138

This movie (***THX 1138***) is actually full of symbolism. But there's this part, almost at the beginning when THX 1138 is watching some holograms after the sexual one, about someone  **being hit by a robot**.

[image: THX 1138 watching]
[image: view of hologram]

Why is he watching this violence? I thought it might represent our inner impulse of rage and violence seeking we calm by watching violent movies or playing videogames, but I'm not sure, could it just be a warning?

He seems to be OK and even enjoy the sight of that brutality. Anyone knows for sure what they tried to represent here?

Comment: Hey Paula, interesting question. Want to point out that *very* few video games existed in 1971 when the film was released, and that the few people likely to have seen or experienced them were the computer scientists who had access to computers (this was before video game arcades and before the desktop computer revolution), and probably not Lucas. All of which, you may already know, so this is just for what it's worth. :)

Comment: Oh I know! sorry I was unclear. I mean _today_, we use those tools, but in this dystopia this might be the way as, there were other ways in the past. I just meant that emotion

Comment: I think the idea is that television has evolved to its purest form, which consists of 1) incomprehensible erudite talking heads, 2) insipid comedy, 3) mindless eroticism and 4) mindless violence. And THX, a good citizen, laps it up without a second thought. (If I can pull up decent screen shots, I'll see if I can turn this into an answer.)

Answer (score 1):

There were no robots. The violence channel was an integrated part of the controlled society, encouraged as an acceptable outlet for the darker urges. The 'citizens' viewing these believed them to be robots, but in fact they were real people who the 'state' had determined to be undesirable & expendable. There was also a deeply ingrained bias against 'natural' born humans as opposed to 'crèche' births. The naturals were portrayed as inferior and more prone to the 'darker' urges.

Comment: A quote proving this, if there is one, would help improve this answer.

Comment: I read the original novel.